# How to create Sharepoint template

Tags: sharepoint-online, template

Have You know any Sharepoint tutorial to create templates for Sharepoint Online. I must create some templates and I want to find out how to creating them.

Have You know any guide about creating templates?

Answer (score 2):

Hello there are two different types of templates: site templates and lists/libraries templates.

1. [Create and use site templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989)
2. [Manage list templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)

Hope it helps!